# SmartThreadPool - Is it possible to pass delegate method with method parameters?

Tags: c#, multithreading, entity-framework

I have a long running process called `ImportProductInformation` called by a consoleapp that I'm trying to speed up, which appears to be an excellent candidate for thread-pooling, so I did a little searching and came across [SmartThreadPool](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/smartthreadpool.aspx) on CodeProject and am trying to implement it.

`ImportProductInformation` currently requires an "item", which is just a single entity-framework row pulled from a list.  `SmartThreadPool` uses a delegate called `"WorkItemCallback"`, but if I build it like below it complains about "Method name expected" in the foreach loop on `smartThreadPool.QueueWorkItem`, as it appears I can't pass my params to the delegated method.  What am I missing here?  I'm sure it's something stupid...noob lacking experience with delegates...any help would be appreciated:

```
    public static void ImportProductInformation_Exec()
    {
        // List
        List<productinformation> _list = GetProductInformation();

        // Import
        if (_list != null)
        {
            SmartThreadPool smartThreadPool = new SmartThreadPool();

            foreach (var item in _list)
            {
                smartThreadPool.QueueWorkItem
                  (new WorkItemCallback
                    (ImportProductInformation(item)));
            }

            smartThreadPool.WaitForIdle();
            smartThreadPool.Shutdown();
        }
    }

    public void ImportProductInformation(productinformation item)
    {
        // Do work associated with "item" here
    }
```

If I change the loop to this I get "Method is used like a Type" in the build error:

```
            foreach (var item in _list)
            {
                ImportProductInformation ipi = 
                  new ImportProductInformation(item);

                smartThreadPool.QueueWorkItem(new WorkItemCallback(ipi));
            }
```

Ended up getting it to work with this:

```
public class ProductInformationTaskInfo
{
    public productinformation ProductInformation;

    public ProductInformationTaskInfo(productinformation pi)
    {
        ProductInformation = pi;
    }
}

public class PI
{
    foreach (var item in _list)
    {
        ProductInformationTaskInfo pi = 
          new ProductInformationTaskInfo(item);
        smartThreadPool.QueueWorkItem
          (new WorkItemCallback
            (ImportProductInformation), pi);
    }

    public static object ImportProductInformation(Object _pi)
    {
        ProductInformationTaskInfo pi = (ProductInformationTaskInfo)_pi;
        var item = pi.ProductInformation;

        // Do work here
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need a thread pool? Can't you just use a `System.Threading.Thread`?

Comment: SmartThreadPool offers so much more than just a standard thread.  If I can't use it I'll definitely fall back on `System.Threading.Thread`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know or have the SmartThreadPool, the following is approximate:

```
foreach (var item in _list)
{
   var itemCopy = item;
   smartThreadPool.QueueWorkItem
              (dummy => ImportProductInformation(itemCopy));
}
```

You may have to do some fixing.
This works because the lambda captures a variable from the containing method. And that's why you need itemCopy.

But note that the normal ThreadPool is *not* suited for longrunning tasks, the same may hold for the SmartThreadPool. It should also keep a limit on the number of threads, and when ImportProductInformation does mainly I/O threading might not help at all.

Comment: Each row execution consumes about 15 seconds, so I'm speculating that the ThreadPool should be suitable.  SmartThreadPool adds quite a bit to the default .NET ThreadPool...  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/smartthreadpool.aspx

Comment: Odd, not sure why, but SmartThreadPool isn't handling the lambda gracefully.  When it builds the WorkItem Queue it repeats one item from the list over and over.  I tried several renditions, but ended up with my original solution with the call-back object.

Comment: @Paul, Did you use the itemCopy var? It's essential.

Comment: Ah, no I didn't...makes sense

Answer (score 1):

You can use anonymous methods:

```
int a = 15;
String b = "hello world!";
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((state)=>SomeFunction(a,b));
```